# Odd behavior iterating through UITableViewCells

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have user input a form based on a UITableView where each cell contains an input control, either a UITextField or a UITextView. I've added Next and Previous buttons to the accessory views of the text fields so that users can navigate forward and backward through the text fields. I have a method that gets the control of the text fields and makes it first responder. Everything so far works properly.

In my method that sets the first responder, I'm calling a helper method that gets the next cell, going either forward or backward:

```
- (UITableViewCell*)nextFormCell:(UITableViewCell*)lastCell isForward:(BOOL)forward
{
    NSIndexPath* path = [_formTableView indexPathForCell:lastCell];
    NSInteger rowIndex = forward ? (path.row + 1) : (path.row - 1);
    UITableViewCell* nextCell = [_formTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:path.section]];
    return nextCell;
}
```

Going forward (next) works flawlessly and this method always returns a cell. However, going backward (previous), the method sometimes returns nil. I have verified that rowIndex contains the correct value going both directions. This doesn't make great sense. If I pass a rowIndex going forward and I get a cell back, why would it not do the same with the same index going backward?

Are there any known issues with navigating backward through UITableView cells? Thanks!

Comment: Most likely because the row above isn't on screen, so the cell doesn't exist...

Comment: Probably the table view controller is releasing the cells that are not in the view and that's why the next cell works fine (because is showed in the view) but previous aren't. Not sure, just a guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting that cells are reused. No cells exist at any given moment except for those displayed on the screen and possibly one or two further forward. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` does not work for every index path, because not all cells exist at any one moment: only the cells actually displayed by the table exist. That is why `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is permitted to return `nil`.

Basically you need to rethink your entire strategy for "navigating" the table. Instead, start by scrolling to the cell you want to navigate to (`scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`). *Now* the cell exists and you can set its text field as first responder.